# Damaged frame on my motorbike

Tags: motorcycle

My 10 year old Yamaha Super Tenere 750 has been off the road for a while as when I got it I learned it had had a bad crash which bent the frame. The rest all works, so I plan to take it to a garage to get it straightened. Apparently this will involve putting it in a jig and pulling it back into shape, then redoing the welds at the front.

Should I be concerned and ride this bike carefully, or even get rid of it? Or is it something that is generally considered a full repair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a reputable shop doing it, I'd get it fixed and ride it.  If done properly frame repairs can be just fine.  It's just if they're NOT done properly that it can be an issue.

Comment: The only suggestion I can add to this is to check into the cost of either a good used frame with paperwork or a replacement frame. My guess is that the latter is probably prohibitively expensive, but it might work out cheaper to find an unbent used frame and rebuild the bike around that.

Comment: @Timo - I hadn't thought of a used frame - will look at costs. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful when buying a used frame, especially on E-Bay. Many look good but are bent due to an accident which led to the bike being parted out in the first place. I'm into older BMW /2 & /5's and many buy frames that are supposedly good yet are bent when checked out in person. They don't give refunds on used vehicle parts either.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed in Australia at least, when a bike gets a bent frame from an accident, it usually turns into a statutory write off.  Meaning, the insurance company must pay the policy out, and the bike is never allowed to be ridden on the road again, not matter what repairs are done.

Probably a rule that came in from back yard operators doing dodgy fix ups on really broken bikes and then getting mates to pass the safety cert?

Either way.  Not sure what you're local laws are, but worth checking to see if you're allowed to re-register a bike thats been in an accident like that.

I also like the other suggestion of maybe grabbing a second hand frame (in good order), or buying another Tenere (same model) with a busted engine, and pilfering the parts you need from that.  Sell the left overs, if you can be bothered.