# 1998 Yamaha XTC750 Super Tenére carburetor air box is not lining up with the engine

Tags: carburetor, yamaha, hose

My Super Tenére mentioned in [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/4101/37) is finally nearing completion, but now it's almost back together I'm thinking the frame must not have been quite straightened back to where it should have been.

Where the boots from the air box should clamp onto the top of the engine, they are just about resting on top of the openings, and they don't line up exactly. These two pictures from the right side of the bike show the problem. The gold ring on the boot should be clamped over the silver ring.

[image]

[image]

Obviously if I had the option I could try and get the frame rejigged again, but I can't do that so I'm looking for options to bridge the gap that will be sufficiently sealed. My local Yamaha garage said they could make something from scratch but they could give no guarantees of cost or time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to bridge it with the original boots in a way that would still let you remove the carbs in the future, but you could try getting rubber pipe fittings (see image below) in the same inner diameter as your boots, but longer, and using them in place of your boots.

You could go as simple or not as necessary, you could even fit balance ports by drilling through the pipe fitting and inserting a hose fitting (if you need to use this on the engine side of the carbs), seal with some sort of flexible adhesive. You may even be able to get away with using an epoxy on the airbox side of this, but my recommendation is that any adhesive you use be flexible if possible as well as heat tolerant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ceshion - I finally sourced couplings like this that I managed to modify. Took a while finding a company that made something suitable.